# What is the meaning of 正好 in 这一年正好秦国军队来打赵国?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

几年后，赵奢去世了。这一年正好秦国军队来打赵国，赵国派老将廉颇带20万大军迎战。

This is from the Standard Course Book of HSK5, chapter 15.

What is the meaning of 正好? Wiktionary says that it means "by chance". Something like coincidentally.

这一年(this year)正好(by chance / coincidentally)秦国(Qin Guo)军队(army)来(arrived)打(to attack)赵国(Zhao Guo)

It really happened accidentally? Or what else 正好 means?

Answer (score 2):

赵奢 is an important general in 赵国. Thus, Qin's invasion *at that precise time*, purely by chance, coincides with the death of the general (which may alter the outcome of the war)

Answer (score 1):

正好 - by chance; it just so happens that ...

Answer (score 0):

几年后，赵奢去世了。这一年正好秦国军队来打赵国，赵国派老将廉颇带20万大军迎战。

In this story, 正好 means there is no relationship between the two events: 赵奢去世 and 秦国来打赵国.

Let's compare the case if without 正好:

几年后，赵奢去世了。这一年秦国军队来打赵国，赵国派老将廉颇带20万大军迎战。

It indicates that the second event 秦国来打赵国 is or may be a consequence of the first event 赵奢去世.

Usually, 正好 means "by chance", “coincidentally”, or "accidentally".

For example, 小张 对 他 太太 说：“在 上班 的 路上 我 正好 碰上 了 前 女友”。他的 太太 不肯 相信。